# Scheme in the header: logo , slogan, image, etc

Tags: css

I want to create a schema like this:

[image]

I'm wondering if it is better create a container for logo and slogan or not.. 
I'm wondering also if it is better create a container for telephone icon, phone1, phone2 and facebook button or not..

Can yo help me?

Answer (score 0):

Try this;

### HTML:

```
<div class="warranty">Warranty image goes here</div>
<div class="logo">LOGO Goes Here</div>
<div class="slogan">Slogan goes here</div>
```

### CSS:

```
.logo{
    background: #4E41FE;
    color: #FFF;
    padding: 4px 4px;
    text-align: center;
    width: 50%;
    margin: 3px;
}
.slogan{
    background: #4E41FE;
    color: #FFF;
    padding: 4px 4px;
    text-align: center;
    width: 50%;
    margin: 3px;
}
.warranty{
    background: #4E41FE;
    color: #FFF;
    padding: 4px 4px;
    text-align: center;
    width: 40%;
    margin-top: 15px;
    float: right;
}
```

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/v4GnU/

Comment: thanks, but I modified my question to give the total vision of my header

Comment: Your best bet is to create a container then, I believe.